# <bean factory-method=""> имеет приоритет выполнения?

Tags: java, spring

Добрый вечер!

Разбираюсь с `Spring` и столкнулся с непониманием ситуации. Объясните пожалуйста, почему при использовании аннотации `factory-method` в `bean` этот `bean` запускается первым?

Вот пример `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd"
       default-init-method="turnOnLights"
       default-destroy-method="turnOffLights">

    <bean id="duke" class="springidol.impl.Juggler">
        <constructor-arg value="15"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="poeticDuke" class="springidol.impl.PoeticJuggler">
        <constructor-arg value="15"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="sonnet29"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sonnet29" class="springidol.impl.Sonnet29"/>

    <bean id="theStage"
          class="springidol.Stage"
          factory-method="getInstance"/>

    <bean id="auditorium" class="springidol.Auditorium"/>
</beans>
```

Вот класс с созданием бинов:

```
public class SpringIdolMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context
                = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-idol.xml");
        Performer jungler = (Performer) context.getBean("poeticDuke");
        try {
            jungler.perform();
        } catch (PerformanceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Auditorium auditorium = (Auditorium) context.getBean("auditorium");
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
}
```

Вот вывод на консоль:

```
STAGE CREATED
LIGHTS ON
JUGGLING 15 BeanBAGS
While reciting.. 
LIGHTS OFF
```

Почему `STAGE CREATED` идет первым? Если закомментить данный бин в XML и запустить программу по новой, то ошибок не будет.

Comment: упоминание о приоритете этого метода в документации я не нашел. по идее вы не должны полагаться на порядок создания. но если вам важен порядок, то вы можете его указать. а так контейнер решает сам в каком порядке создавать бины.

Comment: Порядок запуска строится на основании зависимости, если A зависит от B  то первым будет запускаться B